# Locking the stored procedure and view

Tags: sql-server

How to lock the view and stored procedure in SQL Server to avoid being scripted out by any user? Only SA account should able to delete it. No other permission should be there for SA also.

I am asking this to avoid the table information getting exposed to any user. But only data should able to read from the view that I create.

Comment: Its called permissions... its a big subject... you can read about it on the MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the permissions of the sysadmin role - by definition it MUST have full permissions to do anything with the instance and databases.

To prevent other users from scripting it out then DENY VIEW DEFINITION to the users on those objects